# Using captcha in ember js and mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ember.js, captcha

I'm creating a site using `ember.js` and `asp.net mvc`. In my previous `asp.net` sites, I've used `captchaMVC` (http://captchamvc.codeplex.com/).  But, I can't figure out how to use it with Ember.  Google searches haven't been very helpful for me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to use `captchaMVC` with Ember?

Answer (score 4):

In reCaptcha the challenge request flow (between the user-agent and the reCaptcha challenge resource server) and user response verification flow (typically between your back-end application server and the reCaptcha Verification API server) are handled by [a variety of plugins](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro#Plugins) that abstract this process for you and leave you to deal with its outcome only, both on the front-end and back-end side.

Ember, on the other hand, is a client-side application that should not handle the verification step not to expose your Private reCaptcha Key, amongst other parameters.

Due to these facts, I find it easier to build reCaptcha support manually rather than depend on a specific plugin. [Google's Displaying reCAPTCHA Without Plugins](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) page describes the DIY process well.

I use ember-cli, so `bower install recaptcha-ajax --save` or configure it in bower.json to point to Google's recaptcha-ajax.js directly then import it in Brocfile.

In your view, you can target a specific element like so:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        Recaptcha.create("your_public_key", 'element_id', {
            theme: "red"
            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        });
    }
});
```

In your template, simply embed your this element of `element_id` from above into your form element:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div id="element_id"></div>
</form>
```

and don't forget to exclude Recaptcha in your .jshintrc file:

```
{
    "predef": {
        "Recaptcha": true
    }
}
```

now your back-end form handler will receive `recaptcha_challenge_field` and `recaptcha_response_field` which it has to use in constructing a `POST` request to http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify and you'll have to set a few other params as per the [Google's reCaptcha Verification Flow Document](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).

Comment: did you also imported the lib in Broccoli.js? Or that is not required?

Comment: @EdyBourne Yes, I do mention that you'll have to import `recaptcha-ajax` in your Brocfile in my post, if you read carefully ;)

Comment: Cool! This is how I did in the first place, but I was using the wrong loader.js. Now with the correct version everything is working for me as well. Thanks!

Comment: @EdyBourne I got Uncaught ReferenceError: Recaptcha is not defined in creating the captcha in the view. what't am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Moh you'd probably want to post a question with some code to help you debug your issue really.